# Firebase: Am I only allowed to use third party functions if I pay for a plan?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've been trying to get functions to work for the last few days, and I keep getting errors. In their CLI guides, they say that you can't make API calls to third parties if you're a free user, and I don't know if that also includes just 4 custom lines of code for a function in the index.js file

Answer (score 0):

When your project is on the free Spark plan, Cloud Functions for Firebase only allows calls to Google-owned service. This is done to prevent abuse.

The number of lines of code play no role in this, calls to external services are rejected even if it's in a one-liner.

Comment: They have sample code functions for sending emails to users, and they require gmail credentials. Does this also mean that I am only able to send emails to users that have registered with gmail?

Comment: @HappyMouse you can sign up to the Blaze plan. It is a 'pay what you use' plan. So far I have yet to be charged over a $1 and that is after extensive uploading / downloading in my testing and development.

Comment: You can send email to any user through the gmail API. But that seems unrelated to your original question.