# Google Firebase Functions: webdriver.io get source code of a html-website

Tags: javascript, selenium, firebase, webdriver, google-cloud-functions

Last weekend I have been trying to use Cloud Functions for Firebase to get the source code of a website via webdriver.io.

My code did work when I executed it on my local machine, but when I was trying to run the code with firebase functions it didn't work.
I have a Spark-Account (free) and I guess it is not possible to get information of a website with the a Spark-Account because "Outbound networking" is set to "Google services only". **But I am not sure and maybe there is a possibility to do these kinds of operations via Google Firebase Functions.**

Maybe someone here as more experience with this kind of operations and can tell me the trick to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to non-Google web sites and services from Cloud Functions for Firebase is only possible for projects on a paid plan. Project on the free/spark plan can only access Google-hosted services.

Also:

- [Firebase: Am I only allowed to use third party functions if I pay for a plan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44085970/firebase-am-i-only-allowed-to-use-third-party-functions-if-i-pay-for-a-plan/44087230#44087230)
- [Use firebase cloud function to send POST request to non-google server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415759/use-firebase-cloud-function-to-send-post-request-to-non-google-server/43645498#43645498)
- [What exactly mean “No Outbound Networking” in free tier on Cloud Functions for Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43231446/what-exactly-mean-no-outbound-networking-in-free-tier-on-cloud-functions-for-f/43233738#43233738)
- [Firebase functions - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.sandbox.paypal.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42774807/firebase-functions-getaddrinfo-enotfound-api-sandbox-paypal-com/42775841#42775841)